# How to run node-scheduler once on mentioned time

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-schedule

How to run node-scheduler once on mentioned time not after every minute or second but once according to time passes in params.
i have used this
`let someDate = new Date('22022-01-28T17:59:50.000+00:00')`
and

```
console.log('a')
}
```

but it is NOT WORKING ACCORING TO THE REQUIREMENT
i just want to run once on the provided time .BUt now it is running again and again
i have tried this too `const date = new Date(2022, 1 ,28, 10, 57, 0)`  like i want to run it on 28-01-2022 at 10:57pm
But it is not running

Answer (score 0):

It accepts hour in 24 hour format, so

```
new Date(2022, 1 ,28, 22, 57, 0)
```

should be the correct approach.